# Dart: How do you make a Future wait for a Stream?

Tags: stream, dart, future

I would like to wait for a bool to be true, then return from a Future, but I can't seem to make my Future to wait for the Stream.

```
Future<bool> ready() {
  return new Future<bool>(() {
    StreamSubscription readySub;
    _readyStream.listen((aBool) {
      if (aBool) {
        return true;
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use the Stream method [`firstWhere`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-async/Stream/firstWhere.html) to create a future that resolves when your Stream emits a `true` value.

```
Future<bool> whenTrue(Stream<bool> source) {
  return source.firstWhere((bool item) => item);
}
```

An alternative implementation without the stream method could use the `await for` syntax on the Stream.

```
Future<bool> whenTrue(Stream<bool> source) async {
  await for (bool value in source) {
    if (value) {
      return value;
    }
  }
  // stream exited without a true value, maybe return an exception.
}
```

Comment: Do we have to create a future builder for it?

Comment: there is also .asFuture()  on .listen() method if you want to use a 3rd option :)

Answer (score 5):

```
Future<void> _myFuture() async {
  Completer<void> _complete = Completer();
  Stream.value('value').listen((event) {}).onDone(() {
    _complete.complete();
  });
  return _complete.future;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.